# Yii2 Kartik Extension File Not Found for generating PDF

Tags: pdf, export, yii2

When I try to export PDF, I get the following error:

```
This webpage is not available.
The webpage at    http://dev.eluminousdev.com/rode_survey/admin/reports/excludedcontributors might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

It works fine for Excel or csv.
What can be the issue ? 
Here is my export configuration.I have not made any changes in it.

```
<?php $gridColumns = [
                        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                                        'contributor_name',
                                        [
                                          'attribute'=>  'name',
                                          'label' => 'Survey',
                                        ],
                                        'quarter',
                                        [
                                          'attribute'=>'survey_template_question_id',
                                          'label' => 'Question',
                                        ],
                                        [
                                          'attribute'=>  'node',
                                          'label' => 'node',
                                        ],
                                        'value',
                                        'exclude_reason'
                        ];?>
                            <?php echo ExportMenu::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'fontAwesome' => true,
'dropdownOptions' => [
    'label' => 'Export All',
    'class' => 'btn btn-default'
]
 ]) . "<hr>\n";
                            echo  \kartik\grid\GridView::widget([
                                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                                'columns' => $gridColumns,
                  'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-success'],

                ]); ?>
```

Comment: show export configuration.

Comment: This works without pagiantion.But when there are more records , Iam getting this error.

Comment: Did you got the solution ? I am also getting the same error

Comment: Is this fixed @user7282

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem some days ago. In my log file (yii2 builtin log, default location in `/runtime/logs`), I found my app (apache user) didn't have permission to put contents in `/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfontdata`. Changing folder permission solved the problem.

```
chmod -R 777 /vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfontdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `use \mPDF;` on `vendor/kartik-v/yii2-export/ExportMenu.php`
and be sure you have on your composer.jso file

```
"require": {
  ...
  "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "dev-master",
  ...
}
```

This work for me.